# How to decided between font size, margins and png() parameters to achieve good definition and consistent visualisation?

Tags: r, ggplot2, png, visualization

This is a question that has me banging my head against a wall for a while now. Much of R coding produces consistent results when used for analysis, in a sense that sometimes there are more than one ways to achieve something but your output would be something shareable and consistent. Let's say a dataframe or a datatable and so on and so forth.

However, I'm finding myself struggling to understand how can I achieve a mainstreamed process when generating plots. Font size, margin size, height, width and resolution. All those influence each other.

You change your resolution and suddenly your font size changes drastically when saving with `png()`. You go back and you change the dimensions and there you are with extremely small font size or with a pixeled chart looking at you.

So, because I still trust in the `ggplot` and `png()` process and believe that it must be me that messes up or doesn't do the correct steps in his workflow the question is:

**What is the sweet point between all those factors that makes plotting with R easy, consistent and high-quality?**

I understand that some of these factors cannot be standardised since it depends on the amount of information and how complex a chart is. **But how do others ensure consistent font size against changes in resolution, height, width and plot margins?**

I've came across some useful resources such as:

[https://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2009/01/10-tips-for-making-your-r-graphics-look-their-best.html][1]

[https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200488548-Problem-with-Plots-or-Graphics-Device][1]

But none really speaks to how you mainstream a visualization process in R. Still great tips though.

Any advice or ideas are honestly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: For the moment the only effective way I have found is to configure my plot with ggplot (fix my font size, my margins and generally how it looks) and then opening the zoom panel of Rstudio and saving it with right-click  and *save image as* instead of saving it with png() or any other similar function to avoid distorting my ggplot configuration. Which is funny but effective, high quality and actually the closest to how it was originally plotted.